# how to type in local language in text box?

Tags: internationalization, vs-web-application-project

now we are able type in English in a text box in a web based application and than it can be converted to desired language but my problem is i want to type the text in my local language and convert them to another. what should i do now?

help me please

pleas give me solution for the above problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert between languages you need to either:

- hire translators (who understand both languages, and are preferably native speakers of the target language) to do it manually (expensive, slow)
- use translation software (cheap, very low quality) such as the [Google Translate API](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html).

Comment: Google Translate API helps us to translate the entered text(english) to desired language(local) but my question is to type the text in local language and than convert them to english or whatever so

Comment: You can set any supported language as the target language.

Answer (score 0):

The input language on a web page is set to the browser locale, if I am not mistaken.

This is not a java question.

Comment: Hi mcfinnigan, yes this is not a java question but need to do the same in java web based application.